# OpenMDAO global optimizer

Tags: python, optimization, openmdao

I'm new to OpenMDAO and wanna know if there is a list of all contained optimizers. It seems that in the [homepage of OpenMDAO](http://openmdao.org/) it says

> 'OpenMDAO works with both gradient-free (e.g., genetic algorithm, particle swarm) and gradient-based optimization methods'

but I can't find a full list on its homepage or on the web.

Where can I get it?

Comment: In the PyOpt wrap there's a NSGA2 [non-dominating sorting genetic algorithm] (http://www.pyopt.org/reference/optimizers.nsga2.html) which can do global optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The online documentation provides your answer:
http://openmdao.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.3/srcdocs/packages/drivers/scipy_optimizer.html#module-openmdao.drivers.scipy_optimizer

The above is one of several, and the reader needs to navigate the site for more.  Note that the reader must always select the version applicable or "latest".

Comment: thanks SOERJ,  but the scipy_optimizer you've provided are some local optimzers, not exactly what I'm looking for..

Comment: Truncate the posted URL to "drivers" to see the list.  Note the wrapper for pyOpt which includes genetic algorithms.  http://openmdao.readthedocs.io/en/latest/srcdocs/packages/openmdao.drivers.html

Answer (score 0):

Once you have installed your OpenMDAO package, you can find few drivers in that folder. Apart from that there is a PyOptSparse package which contains few of the other gradient free optimizers. I think most of the optimizers will be covered by this.